# How to send and receive array from firestore database? (Android, iOS)

Tags: arrays, database, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I am successfuly performing CRUD operations in my firestore database (strings and numbers).

However I am unable to save and read an array to firestore. It shows me this error, which I was unable to sovle. This is the error message I get:

**ANDROID:**

Error 1

**CS1950: The best overloaded Add method 'Dictionary<string, Object>.Add(string. Object)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments**

Error 2

**CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from "System.Array" to "Java.Lang.Object"**

```
public bool Insert_restaurantInfo(RestaurantInfoModel restaurantInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            var restaurantInfoDocument = new Dictionary<string, Java.Lang.Object>
            {
                {"restaurantId", Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.Instance.Uid},
                {"categories", restaurantInfo.Categories}
            };

            var collection = FirebaseFirestore.Instance.Collection("restaurants");
            collection.Add(new HashMap(restaurantInfoDocument));

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[image]

---

**iOS:**

Error 1

**CS1503: Argument1: Cannot convert from 'System.Array' to 'Foundation.NSCoder'**

[image]

```
public bool Insert_restaurantInfo(RestaurantInfoModel restaurantInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            var keys = new[]
            {
                new NSString("restaurantId"),
                new NSString("categories")
            };

            var values = new NSObject[]
            {
                new NSString(Firebase.Auth.Auth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.Uid),
                new NSArray(restaurantInfo.Categories)
            };



            var document = new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>(keys, values);

            var collection = Firebase.CloudFirestore.Firestore.SharedInstance.GetCollection("restaurants");
            collection.AddDocument(document);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Data model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;

namespace tipAppRestaurant.Model
{
    public class RestaurantInfoModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string RestaurantId { get; set; }
        public Array Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: why are you using Java and Obj-C types instead of .NET types?

Comment: I was following the course that I bought... ( So is there a better way?)

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't use .NET types like `System.Object`

Answer (score 0):

```
  var restaurantInfoDocument = new Dictionary<string, Java.Lang.Object>
        {
            {"restaurantId", Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.Instance.Uid},
            {"categories", restaurantInfo.Categories}
        };
```

Since you defined the child's type of HashMap is `<string, Java.Lang.Object>`,so you need to put an object into the HashMap instead of `System.Array`.

```
 public class RestaurantInfoModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public Array Categories { get; set; } // it is an array not an object
}
```

**Note:**

There is a similar thread, you can refer to it here: [Adding document to Cloud Firestore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/204337/adding-document-to-cloud-firestore-with-xamarinand.html).